# Differentiation of an integral function

Tags: real-analysis

Let
$$F (t) =\int_{x=0}^t \lfloor x\rfloor dx,$$

in which $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $x$

1. Determine all the real numbers $t$ at which $F$ is differentiable
2. Determine all the real numbers $t$ at which $F$ is continuous but not differentiable

Comment: You might want to check your entry as the integral text is broken over 2 lines. Also what is $i$?

Comment: I edited your question. Please check if it correct.

Comment: @MrYouMath yes it is correct. Sorry for typing it wrongly

Comment: @user499968 and what have you tried? Is this continuous at $1.5$? How about at $1$?

Comment: @gt6989b for part1 .. i got it is differentiable at all points except 1,2 , 3.... am i right?

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you this function is differentiable at points where the integrand is continuous (the floor function is piecewise constant, it's continuous a lot of places).

A quick computation will show that the function is not differentiable at the integers: Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{h}\int_n^{n+h}\lfloor x \rfloor\mathrm dx=n
$$
while 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{1}{h}\int_n^{n+h}\lfloor x \rfloor\mathrm dx=n-1
$$
thus 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_n^{n+h}\lfloor x \rfloor\mathrm dx=F'(n)
$$
does not exist.